# SQL insert multiple data in a specific column (python)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite

Hi have the following code:

```
def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST(Tournament TEXT, MATCH_TIME TEXT, TEAM_1 TEXT, TEAM_2 TEXT)')

create_table()


def data_entry_tournament():
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO TEST(TOURNAMENT) VALUES (?)",
        (Tournament.text.strip()))
    conn.commit()
def data_entry_Time_Event():
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO TEST(MATCH_TIME) VALUES (?)",
        (Time_Event.text.strip()))
    conn.commit()
def data_entry_TEAM_1():
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO TEST(TEAM_1) VALUES (?)",
        (Team_1.text.strip()))
    conn.commit()
def data_entry_TEAM_2():
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO TEST(TEAM_2) VALUES (?)",
        (Team_2.text.strip()))
    conn.commit()

        driver.get(link)

        Tournament = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h2[class='sport-title']")
        if Tournament.text is not "":
            data_entry_tournament()
        for row in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tbody[class='ng-scope']"):
            Time_Event = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")[0]
            Team_1 = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")[1]
            Team_2 = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")[7]
            if Time_Event.text is not "":
                data_entry_Time_Event()
            if Team_1.text is not "":
                data_entry_TEAM_1()
            if Team_1_odds.text is not "":
                data_entry_TEAM_1_ODD()
            if Team_2.text is not "":
                data_entry_TEAM_2()

c.close()
conn.close()
```

My problem is that the output inside SQL is totally wrong, for every row there is only one character and the text is in vertical (and split it in every column in different row).

What i would like to have is the following table for example:

**TOURNAMENT | MATCH_TIME | TEAM_1 | TEAM_2**

EURO 2016 | 18:00 | SPAIN | ITALY

EURO 2016 | 12:00 | HUNGARY | PORTUGAL

and so on...

I'm new in python and sql so I'm sorry if the above code is really bad.

How can i solve the problem and display everything correctly?
Is there a better and faster method than what I wrote above, to achieve the same result?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executemany()` executes the SQL statement once for each element in the list.

You did not give it a list but a string, so it executed the SQL statement once for each element in the string, i.e., once for each character.

Just use `execute()` for a single execution, and don't forget the comma to make a single-element tuple:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO TEST(TOURNAMENT) VALUES (?)",
        (Tournament.text.strip(),))
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! You are a great... Now is much better! the text appear in the correct way, but is still not in the same row (it's like oblique, I mean every text in the correct column but a different row, instead of in the same level. How can i solve this?

Comment: That would be a new question.